# How to enter the Input and Output data into javascript to solve the task?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I'm trying to solve this problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/HOTELS/

I did it this way

```js
var A = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5];
    var B = [];
    var n = 5
    var m = 12
    big = -1;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        sum=0;
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            sum += A[j];
            if (sum < m) { B[i] = sum; continue; }//B[i] становится равным сумме
            if (sum > m) { B[i] = (sum - A[j]); break; }
            if (sum == m) {
              B[i] = sum //B[i] становится равным сумме 
                break;
            }
        }
        if (B[i] > big)
            big = B[i];
    }
    alert(big);
```

Now I need to somehow send the solution through "Submit solution" and here I am experiencing problems. How do I properly change my code so that my decisions are accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply this algorithm

- **Iterate** all items of the array and calculate the sum of each element (including current and after current element)
- **Filter** out sums greater than `m`
- If the **sum** value reaches `m`, stop the iteration and return the value.
- Or find the **max sum value** for each of the item in the array.

Sample implementation

```
var maxValue = 12;
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5].reduce( (a,c,i,ar) => {
   a = a < maxValue ? Math.max( a, Math.max.apply( null, ar.slice( i ).map( ( s, ind ) => ar.slice( ind ).reduce( ( u, v ) => u + v, 0 ) ).filter( k => k <= maxValue ) ) ) : a; 
   return a;
}, 0);
```

**Demo**

```js
var maxValue = 12;
var fnMaxConsecutive = ( arr, maxValue ) => 
    arr.reduce( (a,c,i,ar) => {
       a = a < maxValue ? Math.max( a, Math.max.apply( null, ar.slice( i ).map( ( s, ind ) => ar.slice( ind ).reduce( ( u, v ) => u + v, 0 ) ).filter( k => k <= maxValue ) ) ) : a; 
       return a;
    }, 0);

console.log( fnMaxConsecutive ( [2, 1, 3, 4, 5], 12 ) );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I did not understand how to enter data on the site so that the program accepts the answer

Comment: I am directly passing the array and the max value to the function, while you need to process the inputs from to program on the site first. Intent of this answer is to tell how to get that max value rather than spoon feeding the submit-able answer to you.